# Create file from bytes stored as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I have a use case where I am getting a blob back from the database which I have to convert to a binary file. Python stores this as a string although it is actually bytes. When I try to write as binary I get a Type Error, str not accepted.

I wrote some sample code to reproduce what the variable looks like. I have seen sample code in other languages where this task is rather easy. Help in solving this problem using python 3 would be greatly appreciated. It is probably something very simple that I am missing and I was unable to find an answer online.

```
import binascii

f = open('test.xlsx', 'rb')
content = binascii.hexlify(f.read())
f.close

output = content.decode("utf-8")

#output2 = hex(int(output, 16))

f = open('temp', 'wb')
f.write(output) #TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' 
f.close()

#Convert back to type bytes and recreate the file
```

Comment: Try `f.write(bytes(output, 'utf-8'))`

Comment: Try to convert the string to a byte-array, e.g. gg=bytearray(textstring,'latin-1'), and write that out.

Comment: Don't `binascii.hexlify` the data from the input file. Just `read()` it and write it. The data read from a file in binary mode already is a bytes-like object. `hexlify` is turning it into a utf-8 string in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
f.write(bytearray(output,"utf-8"))
```

instead of:

```
f.write(output) #TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

to solve the problem. Although it seems not to be the most pythonic way to do it.